# How to label a pgfplot from top to bottom?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I just started using pgfplots for diagramms in my paper. I am using a double column layout and want to create the diagramms with the intend that they fit in a single column if possible.

I find it a bit annoying that the reader needs to tilt its head to the left to read the y axis label. I wondered if i could make a y axis label look like this:

[image]

Here is a small diagramm for testing purposes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[   
    ybar,
    ymajorgrids,
    axis lines*       = left,
    ylabel            = {Lorem},       
    xlabel            = {Ipsum},
    xtick             = {2016, 2017, 2018, 2019},
    symbolic x coords = {2016, 2017, 2018, 2019},
]
    \addplot[red!20!black,fill=red!80!white] coordinates
    {(2016,58.8) (2017,93.7) (2018,96.5) (2019,96.4)};
    
    \addplot[red!20!black,fill=blue!80!white]coordinates
    {(2016,93.8) (2017,87.3) (2018,82.3) (2019,77.7)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Could be as simple as `node[align=center]{T\\A\\S\\K}`?.

Comment: Sorry this did not work for me. I added a demo diagramm that i used to test possible answers.

Comment: replace `ylabel            = {Lorem},` by `ylabel style={rotate=-90,align=center},
    ylabel            = {T\\A\\S\\K},`.

Comment: @abcdefg This worked perfectly. Thank you very much :). I tried this approach yesterday myself but without the align it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by @abcdefg:

ylabel style = {rotate = -90, align = center},
ylabel       = {L\o\r\e\m},

Example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[   
    ybar,
    ymajorgrids,
    axis lines*       = left,
    ylabel style      = {rotate = -90, align = center},     
    ylabel            = {L\\o\\r\\e\\m},     
    xlabel            = {Ipsum},
    xtick             = {2016, 2017, 2018, 2019},
    symbolic x coords = {2016, 2017, 2018, 2019},
]
    \addplot[red!20!black,fill=red!80!white] coordinates
    {(2016,58.8) (2017,93.7) (2018,96.5) (2019,96.4)};
    
    \addplot[red!20!black,fill=blue!80!white]coordinates
    {(2016,93.8) (2017,87.3) (2018,82.3) (2019,77.7)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]